# Need example android Bluetooth permission code

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-bluetooth, android-12

I need an example java code of Bluetooth permissions. Android 12.

I know that I have to put this in the AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
```

From my research I think I have to use these tools to get my phone to ask me for Bluetooth permissions:

```
ActivityCompat
ContextCompat
PackageManager
onRequestPermissionsResult
```

But no luck after many hours of tests.
I even tried using libraries from GitHub to ask for "easy" permissions for me but no luck:

https://github.com/googlesamples/easypermissions
https://github.com/guolindev/PermissionX

I tried lowering my target SDK version so I don't need to ask for the user entry but "AndroidX" gave me an error telling that its not compatible with lower SDK's.

It would help me a ton if you have a basic working Bluetooth app java code so I can figure out how to code my own app.

---

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For the new Bluetooth permissions on Android 12, you need these permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" />
```

You can refer to [this blog post](https://xizzhu.me/post/2021-10-05-android-12-bluetooth-permissions/) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

For bluetooth permission on Android 12, you need these permission, depend on your usage:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc" android:required="true" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le" android:required="true" />
```

In your activity, you can add this to check the permission is allowed or not:

```
private static final int ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION_RESULT_CODE = 4;
    private static final int BLUETOOTH_RESULT_CODE = 5;
    private static final int DANGEROUS_RESULT_CODE = 1;

if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                        ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION_RESULT_CODE);
            }
            else if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH},
                        BLUETOOTH_RESULT_CODE);
            }
            else if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                            new String[]{Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN},
                            DANGEROUS_RESULT_CODE);
                }
            }
            else if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                            new String[]{Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT},
                            DANGEROUS_RESULT_CODE);
                }
            }
```

To understand more, you can check [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#BLUETOOTH_CONNECT).